# How to cache model in custom module using magento

Tags: php, magento, caching

I have custom module. In the model I have a class XXX and method YYY. In this method I do request to remote server using cURL. I want to cache this result using magento cache. How I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this just replace the rss with you cUrl call

```
$url = 'http://www.site.com';
$cache = Mage::getSingleton('core/cache');
$key = md5($url);

if(! $rss = $cache->load($key)){
    $objDOM = new DOMDocument();
    $objDOM->load($url);
    $rssXml = $objDOM->getElementsByTagName("item");

    $rss = array();
    foreach( $rssXml as $value ){
        $data['title'] = $value->getElementsByTagName("title")->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $data['description'] = $value->getElementsByTagName("description")->item(0)->nodeValue;

        $rss[] = $data;
    }

    $cache->save(urlencode(serialize($rss)), $key, array("homepage_cache"), 60*60);
}
else{
  $rss = unserialize(urldecode($rss)); 
}

print_r($rss);
```

Read more @ http://www.nicksays.co.uk/2010/07/developers-guide-magento-cache/

Comment: It works perfect. Thank you very much. Can you just explain me what you use this parameters for: array("homepage_cache"), 60*60. May be 60*60 is the time in seconds and after that the cache will be refresh, but for homepage_cache I am not sure?

Comment: It is use to 'group' cache, so that you can delete all cache that belong to 'homepage_cache' by doing $cache->flush('...') (mass removal) ... 60*60 is the time in second.. take a look at the link above